Extreme RMSE Validation Score in Time Series Model
I have a dataset consists of hourly data with 4000 rows and 3 numeric columns. It doesn't have clear trend or seasonality. I've shared a graph of stl decomposition together with original lineplot of one target column below.
This is the graph of one target column
And i use this code for training:
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5,gap=24)
train_rmse_scores = []
val_rmse_scores = []

for fold, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(tscv.split(melen_forecast_df), start=1):
    train_df, test_df = melen_forecast_df.iloc[train_index], melen_forecast_df.iloc[test_index]
    
    # Create features only using the training set
    X_train = create_all_features(train_df)
    y_train = train_df[targets]
    
    # Create features for the test set
    X_test = create_all_features(test_df)
    y_test = test_df[targets]
    
    X_train = X_train.iloc[4:]
    y_train = y_train.iloc[4:]
    X_test = X_test.iloc[4:]
    y_test = y_test.iloc[4:]
    
    print(f"Fold {fold} - Training data shape: {X_train.shape}, Validation data shape: {X_test.shape}")

    model = MultiOutputRegressor(xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror',n_estimators=500,learning_rate=0.015))
    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    # Predict and calculate RMSE for training set
    y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
    train_rmse_per_target = [np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train.iloc[:, i], y_train_pred[:, i])) 
                             for i in range(y_train.shape[1])]
    train_rmse_scores.append(train_rmse_per_target)
    
    for i, rmse in enumerate(train_rmse_per_target, start=1):
        print(f"Fold {fold} - Training Target {i} RMSE: {rmse:.4f}")
    
    # Predict and calculate RMSE for validation set
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    val_rmse_per_target = [np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test.iloc[:, i], y_pred[:, i])) 
                           for i in range(y_test.shape[1])]
    val_rmse_scores.append(val_rmse_per_target)
    
    for i, rmse in enumerate(val_rmse_per_target, start=1):
        print(f"Fold {fold} - Validation Target {i} RMSE: {rmse:.4f}")

    # Calculate and print average RMSE across all folds
    avg_train_rmse = np.mean(train_rmse_scores, axis=0)
    avg_val_rmse = np.mean(val_rmse_scores, axis=0)

Im trying to train those 3 target columns with MultiOutputRegressor, wrapping XGBoostRegressor. My problem is the RMSE score is too high for both train and validation. Even after using optuna to tune the hyperparameters it didnt seem good. I even saw a validation RMSE equals 7000. At this point i cant decide if my model is overfitting or underfitting because if i start training with basic features my validation score starts from very high validation RMSE and goes on. I think i do critical mistake at certain point.
